# JavaScrpt math: solve simultaneous equation

Tags: javascript, math

I am new to JS, I need to solve this type of equation: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zbqt1g27lb in JavaScript, is there any way to do this?
9x^2+4y^2-3x+4y=6 
9x^2+4y^2+3x-3y=6 
The coefficients may change, but the unknowns are always in that format.  
Is there any function in JS.Math I can directly use? 
I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: Show the equation(s), what you've tried.

Comment: "Solve" in what sense?  Looking at the graphing calculator link, it would appear that there are multiple/infinite valid answers for x and y in these equations...

Comment: @AlexanderNied Weilory wants the points of intersection - they are treated as a system of simultaneous equations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a maths problem, not a javascript problem. I would recommend solving it algebraically first (factorising to get one in terms of the other, and then using substitution) until you have an expression for x and y in terms of the coefficients. Then write javascript code to evaluate those expressions given the coefficients. You will probably need to evaluate four expressions, due to the ± nature of square roots.

There are various methods for computationally solving *any* equation, but they would be inefficient in this case, since the form of the equations are known.